# How to Convert ISO String in DateTime

Tags: apex, datetime

```
String date = '2020-05-15T08:48:17.000+0000'
```

I want to convert String which is in ISO format to DateTime in apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
String inpputString = '2020-05-15T08:48:17.000+0000';
DateTime resultDateTime = DateTime.ValueofGmt(inpputString.replace('T', ' ')); 

System.Debug('resultDateTime>> '+resultDateTime);
```

Output:

```
16:19:36:002 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|resultDateTime>> 2020-05-15 08:48:17
```